# Hide presentMediaPlayerController Swift 3 WatchKit

Tags: swift3, media-player, watchkit, hidden, watchos-2

Is there any way to hide the media player or display it on a sublayer where it won't be seen? I can play sounds directly from the watch, but the media player looks bad when its a sound effect.

```
func playSound(name: String, time: Double){
         let assetURL: URL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: name, withExtension: "wav")!
        let options: [AnyHashable: Any] = [WKMediaPlayerControllerOptionsAutoplayKey: true]
        self.presentMediaPlayerController(with: assetURL, options: options, completion: {(_ didPlayToEnd: Bool, _ endTime: TimeInterval, _ error: Error?) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
        })
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + Double(Int64(time * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC), execute: {() -> Void in
            self.dismissMediaPlayerController()
        })
    }
```

[image]